# 500 error when try`s to login djangocms running on supervisorctl

Tags: django-cms, supervisord

I have djangocms web-site on django-1.8 and python3.4. I use Nginx and Gunicorn. When my project runs throuh - "python manage.py runserver" or "gunicorn app.wsgi:appliaction". I can easily login and edit my site. But when i use supervisorctl site works, but when want to enter in administration part - "Server error (500)".I do not know what to do.

P.S. I`m new, and use this guidline to configure my server - https://djbook.ru/examples/62/ (careful a lot of russians words)

Comment: You'll need to check the log files - the cause of the error will be in there.

Comment: Please can you say me which log files should i check?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Basically whatever error logs get created by Nginx & Gunicorn. There'll be a cause for your 500 error in logs somewhere.